# How to download Salesforce files From community? LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, community, experience-cloud

Apex :

```
private static final String  BASE_URL = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
@AuraEnabled
public static List<FileData> telechargerConv(String recordId){
  List<ContentDocumentLink> links=[SELECT ContentDocumentId,LinkedEntityId FROM ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntityId=:recordId];
    Set<Id> ids=new Set<Id>();
    for(ContentDocumentLink link:links)
    {
        ids.add(link.ContentDocumentId);
    }
    List<ContentVersion> versions=[SELECT VersionData,Title,ContentDocumentId,FileExtension FROM ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocumentId = :ids AND IsLatest = true];
    
    List<FileData> files=new List<FileData>();
    for(ContentVersion attach:versions)
     {
        FileData data=new FileData();
        if(versions!=null && versions.size()>0)
        {
            data.Content = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(versions[0].VersionData);
            data.ContentType = ContentType(versions[0].FileExtension);
        }
        data.DownloadUrl =BASE_URL + '/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/'+versions[0].ContentDocumentId;
        data.FileUrl =BASE_URL + '/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload?rendition=THUMB720BY480&versionId='+versions[0].Id;
        files.add(data);
    }
    return files;
}
@AuraEnabled
public static string ContentType(string fileType)
{
    switch on fileType.toLowerCase()
    {
        when 'docx'
        {
            return 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document';
        }
        when 'csv'
        {
            return 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
        }
        when 'wav'
        {
            return 'audio/wav';
        }
        when 'wmv'
        {
            return 'video/x-ms-wmv';
        }
        when 'mp3'
        {
            return 'audio/mpeg';
        }
        when 'mp4'
        {
            return 'video/mp4';
        }
        when 'png'
        {
            return 'image/png';
            
        }
        when 'pdf'
        {
            return 'application/pdf';
            
        }
        when else {
            return 'image/jpeg';
        }
    }
}
public class FileData 
{
    @AuraEnabled
    public string Content{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public string ContentType{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public string FileUrl{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public string DownloadUrl{get;set;}
}
```

JS :

```
telechargerConv({ recordId : currentRow }).then(result => {

        console.log('download',result);
    })
```

i retrieve well my files :

[image]

But i'm stuck on how to run the Url and download the files ..

The **URL** should be like this in order to download file in community ?????:

```
https://DOMAIN.sandbox.lightning.force.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/FILEID
```

Answer (score 1):

You have run a loop on your result and navigate to download url using window.open like this:-

```
telechargerConv({ recordId : currentRow }).then(result => {
    result.forEach(element => {
        window.open(element.DownloadUrl, '_blank');
    });
})
```

This will open a new tab, download the file and close it automatically for each of the item in your result.

---

### Update

the download url should look like this:-

https://db0000000dzqemau-dev-ed.develop.lightning.force.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/068B000000BU4wNIAT?operationContext=S1

i.e  `window.location.origin +'/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/'+ version id+'?operationContext=S1'`

you need to make sure you have download url as above format

### Again Update

if you are in community, then your url should be like this:-

```
String fileDownloadUrl = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()  + '/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/' + contentDocument Id + '?operationContext=S1';
```

the only difference i can see in your code is you are missing `'?operationContext=S1'` in url

Another way of accessing the download url is using **[contentdistribution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentdistribution.htm)** object

sample example can be found here:- https://gist.github.com/lukethacoder/818d4dba3f7fb00ea861a76fe85fc1a3

Comment: the issue is related to `DownloadUrl` , even when i tried to execute the url in new window it doesn't work .. file doesn't open in community

Comment: @user122708, please check the update

Comment: my download URL looks like this : https://"DOMAIN".sandbox.my.site.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/"FileID"  , the button is located in Community portal page

Comment: @user122708 I have added the update again, please check

Comment: So the right url is this : `data.DownloadUrl =URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()  + '/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/' + contentDocument.Id + '?operationContext=S1';` in order to download all files ? on click buton can't understand why it redirect me to another url ( login to another community ) : `https://DOMAIN.sandbox.my.site.com/"IDEES"/login?ec=302&in...`

Comment: i don't think it's the right URL , **contentDocument.Id** isn't the Id of the file?

Comment: both contentversion id and contentdocument id will work as far as i have tested in my org.

Comment: the issue is related to URL :  with : `my.site.com` url doesn't work and with `force.com` it work so since i'm in commnity i think that i need to change **BASE_URL** ..

Comment: Do you know how to change the contentDocument.Id in url file based on file length ? if there 5 files so i need to download all file so 5 urls with different contentDocument.Id ..

Comment: are you using force.com sites or community experience site?

Comment: community experience

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/306939/download-contentdocument-in-community-redirect-to-maintenance-site it will solve your issue. Let me know if it works, i will add in answer

Comment: i've already tried that , in my case i have many files to more than one **contentDocumentId**

Comment: you need to just populate the url in your wrapper list in apex. Then, use my code to navigate to download url

Comment: the URL should be like this `https://DOMAIN.sandbox.lightning.force.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/document/download/FILEID`  but i wont it to be static , with the domain ..