# How to retrieve files (ContentDocumentId) stored on Account by querying Contact's LinkedEntityId?

Tags: apex

Apex:

```
 public static Map<ID, String> telechargertousDoc(String recordId) {
    // Get record file IDs        
    List<ContentDocumentLink> files = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId = :recordId];
    List<ID> fileIDs = new List<ID>();
    for (ContentDocumentLink docLink : files) {
        fileIDs.add(docLink.ContentDocumentId);
    }

    List<ContentVersion> docs = [SELECT ContentDocumentId, FileExtension, Title 
        FROM ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocumentId IN : fileIDs];
    Map<ID, String> mapIdTitle = new Map<ID, String>();
    for (ContentVersion docLink : docs) {
        mapIdTitle.put(docLink.ContentDocumentId, docLink.Title);
    }
    return mapIdTitle;
}
```

I've the RecordId of the custom object but i don't have the recordId of the related object i know only it's name , my goal is retrieve file in the custom object and in its related object.. i retrieve the 2 ids like `List<***> ids = [SELECT id,                              (SELECT id,Name FROM Formations_de_la_Convention__r           LIMIT 1)         FROM Convention_Formation__c WHERE Id =: recordId]; How to retrieve the 2 ids from this query so i can use them in clause where of : SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId In *******`

But how to stock the ids?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: As mentioned , is to retrieve all files in custom object and which are  related to custom object  as well .. to finally download them , i'm still stucked in this question [My question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/387316/how-to-download-salesforce-files-from-community-lwc/387317?noredirect=1#comment560054_387317) can't find the good url in community but for this question i want to retrieve files stocked in custom object and which are related to custom object as well .. i pass the `record Id` as parameter and i want to retrieve all file .. is this doable?

Comment: is this doable please? do you have any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Can't be done.  You must filter on LinkedEntityId or ContentDocumentId, and either way,  use no more than 200 ID values

Comment: So i can't retrieve Contact's file when querying LinkedEntityId of Account?

Comment: You'd have to query all the contacts for the account first,  then use those ID values.

Comment: Example : `List<***> ids = [SELECT id,                     
        (SELECT id,Name FROM Formations_de_la_Convention__r 
         LIMIT 1)
        FROM Convention_Formation__c WHERE Id =: recordId];`

How to retrieve the 2 ids from this query so i can use them in clause where of : `SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId In *******`

Comment: @sfdcfox tbh at one level subqueries always worked for me against `ContentDocumentLink` and so in the scenario where we want `files attached to all contacts in this account` we can use that subquery filtered by `AccountId`. This, of course, will not work if `contacts to multiple accounts` is on, there two queries will be required.

Answer (score 1):

So it is a bit unclear if this is what you want but it seems you want the following:

```
List<ContentDocumentLink> cdls = [SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId, LinkedEntityId, ContentDocument.Title FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId IN (SELECT Id FROM Formations_de_la_Convention__c WHERE Convention_Formation__c = :recordId)];

Map<Id, String> result = new Map<Id, String>();

for (ContentDocumentLink cdl: cdls) {
    result.put(cdl.ContentDocumentId, cdl.ContentDocument.Title);
}

return result;
```

Comment: the question : How to retrieve files (ContentDocumentId) stored on Account by querying Contact's LinkedEntityId?

Comment: like this : `SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId, ContentDocument.Title, ContentDocument.createdDate, ContentDocument.Createdby.Name, ContentDocument.FileExtension
FROM ContentDocumentLink
WHERE LinkedEntityId IN (SELECT Id FROM Formation_Relative_Convention__c WHERE ConventionFormation__c = : recordId) AND LinkedEntityId =: recordId`

Comment: `Contact's LinkedEntityId` Can you clarify what you mean? `sObject` `Contact` does not have a field `LinkedEntityId`. Please explain